# Style first and last element for each

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, each

I'm trying to style the first and last list item within the "wrapper" class by applying the "red" class. I have multiple sections on the page with the "wrapper" class.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="section">
    <ul class="parent">
      <li class="child">List Item</li>
      <li class="child">List Item</li>
      <li class="child">List Item</li>
      <li class="child">List Item</li>
      <li class="child">List Item</li>
      <li class="child">List Item</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="section">
    <ul class="parent">
      <li class="child">List Item</li>
      <li class="child">List Item</li>
      <li class="child">List Item</li>
      <li class="child">List Item</li>
      <li class="child">List Item</li>
      <li class="child">List Item</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/n2bg3zu4/

Comment: After retagging your question it has now occurred to me that this may or may not actually be a jQuery question. Are you looking for a CSS solution, a jQuery solution, or either one? You'll want to specify this in your question description as it's unclear at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use css3 to do that:

```
.parent li:first-child, .parent li:last-child {
    background-color: red;
}
```

First and last li (list item) will be read in each .parent element

Answer (score 1):

> trying to style the first and last list item within the "wrapper"
>   class

Try utilizing `:nth-of-type()` , `:nth-last-of-type()`

```css
.wrapper li:nth-of-type(1),
.wrapper li:nth-last-of-type(1) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="section">
    <ul class="parent">
      <li class="child">List Item</li>
      <li class="child">List Item</li>
      <li class="child">List Item</li>
      <li class="child">List Item</li>
      <li class="child">List Item</li>
      <li class="child">List Item</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="section">
    <ul class="parent">
      <li class="child">List Item</li>
      <li class="child">List Item</li>
      <li class="child">List Item</li>
      <li class="child">List Item</li>
      <li class="child">List Item</li>
      <li class="child">List Item</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/n2bg3zu4/4/

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can write,

```
$('.wrapper .parent li:first-child, .wrapper .parent li:last-child').addClass('red')
```